# How can I put files in the user's local application data folder in a setup project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I'm working with a visual studio 2008 - You get access to a number of special folders to use if you want to include files within.  One I don't see on the list is the user's local application data folder.  Is there anyway to put files in that folder from within a VS2008 setup project?

Comment: Was this removed in 2008? I have this in my list in 2005.

Answer (score 0):

When I was facing similar challenge, I made it so:

- Created a class library auxiliary project.
- Added the System.Configuration.Install.dll reference.
- Added a new class inheriting from System.Configuration.Install.Installer
- Wrote an override of the Install method to copy the files

In the Setup project, targeted the above mentioned project output to the Application folder and -

In Custom actions (Install group) picked the auxiliary project output from the Application folder.